# Issue encountered using Stripe with Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

I have recently been running into some issues using stripe within Meteor and this community has always been a great help to me so here goes!

I am trying to create a simple website allowing users to create posts paying for a pre-determined fee. $20 per month, $30 for 2 months etc. I have the entire skeleton of the site built i now just need to enable users to pay. While searching around for any information on my scenario i cam across a tutorial.

https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/payments-with-stripe-checkout/

This was a very helpful and informative tutorial. However i ran into some issues along the way. My paths are almost all the exact same however in a few instances i had to change them due to where my pre-existing code was. I cannot find out why this code wont work and i'm hoping a second set of eyes just catches something i missed.

**My settings.json file located in directory directly alongside .meteor file:**

```
{
"public": {
"stripe": "pk_test_jdsoajdanotrealhasodahsd"
},

"private": {
  "stripe": "sk_test_hfsd83totallyreal39u03fda",
  "CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET": "9847934f937ForSureReal49849f"
},

"CLOUDINARY_API_KEY": "fdnk84894wy7f7sdffake8494g",
"CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME": "CompanyName"
```

}

**My Meteor autofom HTML LOCATED IN:/CLIENT/PAGES/POSTS**

```
  <template name="insertPostForm">
  {{#autoForm collection="Posts" id="insertPostForm" type="insert"}}
  <div class="form-group">
    <h4>Length of Post <small></small></h4>
     {{> afFormGroup name="expiryDate" options=expiryOptions}}
   <h3>Information <small></small></h3><hr>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
     {{> afQuickField name='address'}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      {{> afQuickField name='status' options='allowed'}}
    </div>
    <h3>Details <small></small></h3><hr>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      {{> afQuickField name='squareFoot'}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
     {{> afQuickField name='yearBought'}}
    </div>
    {{#unless processing}}
            <p class="alert alert-info">Please select your prefered months of posting time</p>

            <ul class="list-group price-list">
              <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <p class="pull-left"><strong>$32</strong> &mdash; 1 Month</p>
                <a href="#" data-service="1Month" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <p class="pull-left"><strong>$50</strong> &mdash; 2 Months</p>
                <a href="#" data-service="2Months" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <p class="pull-left"><strong>$75</strong> &mdash; 3 Months</p>
                <a href="#" data-service="3Months" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

      {{else}}
        <p class="alert alert-warning"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Processing payment...</p>
      {{/unless}}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Listing</button>
 </div>
 {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

**My service.js file LOCATED IN: CLIENT/PUBLIC/SERVICES.JS**

```
Template.services.onCreated( () => {
  let template = Template.instance();

  template.selectedService  = new ReactiveVar( false );
  template.processing       = new ReactiveVar( false );

  template.checkout = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: Meteor.settings.public.stripe,
    locale: 'auto',
    token( token ) {
      let service = template.selectedService.get(),
          charge  = {
            amount: token.amount || service.amount,
            currency: token.currency || 'usd',
            source: token.id,
            description: token.description || service.description,
            receipt_email: token.email
          };

      Meteor.call( 'processPayment', charge, ( error, response ) => {
        if ( error ) {
          template.processing.set( false );
          Bert.alert( error.reason, 'danger' );
        } else {
          Bert.alert( 'Success!' );
        }
      });
    },
    closed() {
      template.processing.set( false );
    }
  });
});

Template.services.helpers({
  processing() {
    return Template.instance().processing.get();
  },
  paymentSucceeded() {
    return Template.instance().paymentSucceeded.get();
  }
});

Template.services.events({
  'click [data-service]' ( event, template ) {
    const pricing = {
        '1Month': {
          amount: 3200,
          description: "1 Month"
        },
        '2Monthes': {
          amount: 5000,
          description: "2 Monthes"
        },
        '3Monthes': {
          amount: 7500,
          description: "3 Monthes"
        }
    };

    let service = pricing[ event.target.dataset.service ];

    template.selectedService.set( service );
    template.processing.set( true );

    template.checkout.open({
      name: 'Posting Service',
      description: service.description,
      amount: service.amount,
      bitcoin: true
    });
  }
});
```

**My Stripe.JS file LOCATED IN: /SERVER/STRIPE.JS**

```
let Stripe = StripeAPI(Meteor.settings.private.stripe);

Meteor.methods({
  processPayment( charge ) {
    check( charge, {
      amount: Number,
      currency: String,
      source: String,
      description: String,
      receipt_email: String
    });

    let handleCharge = Meteor.wrapAsync( Stripe.charges.create, Stripe.charges ),
        payment      = handleCharge( charge );

    return payment;
  }

});
```

after integrating this code from tutorial into my project whenever i go into command line and type "meteor --settings settings.json"

the first line i get in response is

"ReferenceError : StripeAPI is not defined"
"at server/Stripe.js : 1 : 14"

if i change the first line of my Stripe.js code to (Meteor.private.Stripe) my error changes to

"TypeError : Cannot read property 'stripe' of undefined"

""

I have just been going crazy over here trying to figure this out and thought i might see if one of you fine individuals would be able to assist me in this matter. If you have read this far you have already done me a service, and for that i thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't use `Meteor.wrapAsync` on Stripe functions because stripe functions return a promise.

Comment: After adding mrgalaxy:stripe etc my program now works. however it will not call the stripe payment method any time i click one of the 3 buttons :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: You should never EVER!!!! post your API keys anywhere! Read more [here](http://joshowens.me/environment-settings-and-security-with-meteor-js/).

For your problem: looks like node-stripe is not available on the server. Did you do `meteor add mrgalaxy:stripe` as specified in the [recipe](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/payments-with-stripe-checkout/#tmc-meteor-packages)?

Comment: Yeah i was reading up on that earlier before adding stripe. I was terrified of the ramifications, that is why i entered fake keys ^ lol. They are all just jumbles of letters and numbers not my real keys :P.

Comment: ok! that's good :). did you get it to work then? If yes, please accept my answer. Happy coding.

Comment: It did work! i ran into some other issues after however you helped me solve this problem!